# No module named 'ICE'

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition

I am using my code on jupyter notebook

```
!pip install ICE
!pip install zeroc-ice
```

> Requirement already satisfied: ICE in c:\python3.7\lib\site-packages (0.0.2)

> Requirement already satisfied: zeroc-ice in c:\python3.7\lib\site-package (3.7.4)

```
input=['he and Chazz duel with all keys on the line.']

from ICE import CollocationExtractor

extractor = CollocationExtractor.with_collocation_pipeline('T1' , bing_key = 'Temp',pos_check = False)

print(extractor.get_collocations_of_length(input, length = 3))
```

getting error as:

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 3 input=['he and Chazz duel with all keys on the line.']
> 4
> ----> 5 from ICE import CollocationExtractor
> 6
> 7 extractor = CollocationExtractor.with_collocation_pipeline('T1' , bing_key = 'Temp',pos_check = False)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ICE'

Sorry if it's not properly readable..

Comment: Side note: `import`s  should be at the top of the file, leave the variable declaration after the import.

Comment: Capitalization matters. It's `ice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to import it as 'ice' e.g.

```
import ice
app = ice.cube()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

and for zeroc-ice as

```
import sys, Ice
with Ice.initialize(sys.argv) as communicator:
    obj = communicator.stringToProxy("hello:tcp -h myhost.mydomain.com -p 10000")
    obj.ice_ping()
```